# Python handling memory usage of byte related objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, memory, byte

**Background**

At the moment, I'm working on the compression of an numpy array that contains nine variables and another numpy array that has a size of 110(The sizes are constant, eg, every instance of this object contains nine variables and one numpy array with a size of 110). The nine variables consists of a mixture of floats and integers, while the numpy array within the object also has integer for values. I took a random sample and tried to find the actual size of the object. I did not use

```
sys.getsizeof()
```

Since this method appears to be unreliable for getting the actual size of an object if there are nested objects, I used pympler to calculate the size of my object, which resulted into the following code:

```
print("Size before compression: {}".format(asizeof.asizeof(object) ))
Size before compression: 25200
```

**Problem one**

The next step I did was to split the object into two parts: one part containing the nine variables and one part with the numpy array. When I tried to check the memory usage of these two objects I got the following results:

```
print('Size waveform before compression: {}'.format(asizeof.asizeof(np_array)))
112

print('Size other variables before compression: {}'.format(asizeof.asizeof(other_vars)))
96
```

My question is:

- How is it possible that there is such a size difference compared with the main object? I assume that something is wrong with the way I call the objects, but I'm not sure.

**Problem two**

I compressed the two objects(in this case, I used Pylzma) and received these values:

```
print('Size waveform after compression: {}'.format(asizeof.asizeof(compressed_np_array)))
Size waveform after compression: 5808
print('Size other variables after compression: {}'.format(sys.getsizeof(compressed_vars)))    
Size other variables after compression: 7818
```

This seems more plausible, however, when I combine the two objects to receive one byte object, I got a different memory usage than I was expecting, eg:

```
compressed_record = compressed_vars + compressed_np_array
print("Size after compression: {}".format(asizeof.asizeof(compressed_object)))
Size after compression: 13592
```

I was expecting that the entire object was 13626 instead of the actual value 13592.

- How is it possible that the combined compressed object is smaller than the two separate compressed values? Is it maybe related to memory leaks?

Thanks in advance for reading / answering my question and I'm happy to provide more information where necessary

Comment: You need to provide details, it isn't clear what you are actually doing. Use code to show what you are working with, your description is too vague

Comment: adding 2 objects merges them, then you have 1 object "header" instead of 2. Not surprising that it's smaller once combined. But really there's no way for us to help you further since you don't provide anything like a [mcve]. For instance what is the type of `compressed_vars`, `compressed_np_array`? bytes?

Comment: The nature of your arrays/objects is unclear.  Sounds a bit like one (or both) is object dtype.  I also have no idea what you mean by compression.  We don't normally compress arrays.  In one piece of code you use `+`.  That's meaningless without knowledge of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that your objects are or `bytes` type (probably, since they're the output of a compression module) but that's expected that adding 2 byte objects reduces the size.

```
import sys

a = b'hellow world'
b = b'how are you?'


print(sys.getsizeof(b''))
print(sys.getsizeof(a))
print(sys.getsizeof(b))
print(sys.getsizeof(a+b))
```

result:

```
33
45
45
57
```

you see, the "merged" object is `57` bytes long, where each object is `45` bytes long before adding. That's because the real data is much smaller, you're not considering that `bytes` is an *object* with attributes. See, the size of an empty `bytes` object is `33` on my system.

So by adding 2 bytes objects, I get rid of one set of non-data (object attributes, like size for instance) and the resulting object is slightly smaller.

Anyway your data is big enough to ignore that difference. But when using a lot of small objects, this overhead can consume a lot of memory (like in my example above)